# How to get a new field in results for the searched query in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

So I’m using elasticsearch V2.3.1. Below is my elasticsearch query:

```
GET pibtest1/_search?q=white
{
   "size": 1, 
   "fields": ["U", "UE", "UD", "T"]
}
```

I get the following result after running the above query:

```
{
  "took": 2,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 85,
    "max_score": 0.15116164,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "pibtest1",
        "_type": "SearchTech",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.15116164,
        "fields": {
          "UE": [
            "Some value1"
          ],
          "U": [
            "Some value2"
          ],
          "T": [
            "Some value3"
          ],
          "UD": [
            "Some value4"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

As you can see in the results, Elasticsearch doesn’t provide any information about the query which is searched. In my case, the query is “white”. So is there any way to get the searched query (“white”) in the result? For example, I would like to get something like this in the result ->

```
“query”: “white”
```

I checked the explain API of Elasticsearch. It does provide the details of how the score gets computed but it doesn’t explicitly contain any field for searched query. Thank you everyone.

Comment: Why you also include `newContent` field? Or do you look for a generic solution?

Comment: Hi @alpert,  I have edited the question now. Can you recheck the question?

Comment: Queries can be very complicated and in a very wide range of formats. I didnt see anything about that topic but I dont things what you want is possible.

Comment: _it doesn’t explicitly contain any field for searched query_. Yes, it does: `"description": "weight(_all:white in 0) [PerFieldSimilarity], result of:"`

Comment: Hello @AndreiStefan: Thanks for replying. It has more information associated with the query. It's too complex to what I want. It attaches an explanation field to each and every document returned.

Comment: Then there's no other option

Comment: @AndreiStefan: Okay, thanks. As I'm using Java API to connect to elasticsearch. Is there any method in Java which will do the trick instead?

Comment: Since you have `?q=white` can't you really get it from the method call you pass to ES? I mean it's something that comes from an user passed in as a   parameter probably...

Comment: @AndreiStefan Yes, that's the right way I guess. Thanks for your time. It would have been much simpler in my case though if I had got it in the results.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not possible.